# iPhone sdk: how to increase the local notification count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Hi I am working on Google calendar, I have to remain user events with local notifications, when event starts.

for that I have to show notifications, if user have two events at a time then local notification count has to increase on app icon.(**If I have two events at a time also count is showing only one local notification count on the app icon**).

please suggest me how to increase the local notification count on the app icon.

please check my code.

```
//Local notifications delegates and methods.
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");

if (cls != nil) {

UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
notif.fireDate = [[when startTime] date];
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
notif.alertBody =  titles;// here title is the key word for the event

// Set the action button
notif.alertAction = nil;
notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;


// Specify custom data for the notification
NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:titles forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];

notif.userInfo = userDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
[notif release];

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the variable count contains the correct number to shown on the icon's badge, you simply do the following:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = count;
```

Answer (score 0):

my answer will need a database:

create an array (database) sorted with date and count. When a notification fires up, call it's count and display it using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: badgeSortCount]
```